# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel, Version=10.0.0.0

Tags: c#, pdf, iis, rdlc, asp.net-mvc-5

Using MVC5 with rdlc to generate pdf, it's working fine in localhost, but when i deply the application to server when i try to generate report it has error that some assebly are missing.....

Server Error in '/webapp' Application.

```
    Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel,
 Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
 dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

so far install in

> webs server iis 2012

1- SQLSysClrTypes
2- ReportViewer

after reboot server still while printing the report server error

Comment: Can you see this assembly in your web app bin folder?

Comment: You should install : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45496

Comment: yes i saw there is report viewer , @DavitTvildiani i have already installed, i listed in my question

Answer (score 2):

You are probably missing this assembly in bin folder. This can happen if you reference it in Global Assembly Cache (GAC). Check your project references in Visual Studio, find this assembly, press F4 (you will see it's properties), then set `Copy Local` to true. In this case the assembly will always be copied to bin folder.

Comment: it's true, but now when i deploy in my pc iis it's working fine but not in server 2012 iis even i installed the 1,2 packages which i list in my question

Answer (score 1):

Install this nuget package `Cquential.Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by installing this update from Microsoft.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=27231