# RDLC Report is not working on the live server

Tags: c#, rdlc, asp.net-webpages

Why sometimes `RDlC Report` is not working on the live server , It works correctly in the **localhost** always, But every time am replaced the **new published files** it says the below error. When i republish the files and hosted again next time it will work.

sometimes am getting this error in live production servers

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Comment: close the antivirus temporarily then publish to see if it was blocked by it every first execution.

Comment: I don't have installed any anti-virus to my mechine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel, Version=10.0.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45207154/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-reportviewer-processingobjectmodel-v)